# What is the meaning of "#def" in a Tornado air conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning

I washed the dust off my filters of the Tornado air conditioner unit in my room. After I put them back in place, the air conditioner does not heat: when I put it in "heat" condition, I see "#def" at the top-right corner of the display:

[image]

[image]

When I put it in "fan" mode, it works as usual.

I read the manual, and did not find any explanation about the "#def" symbol. What does it mean? And how can I make the air conditioner heat again?

Comment: perhaps defrost mode?

Comment: Washed, and put back while still wet/damp? Defrost seems quite likely.

Comment: Is the manufacturer "Tornado?" What's the model number?

Comment: If it is indeed "defrost", but what can I do to make it heat again?
--
I do not see any number on it, but there is text "Design Inverter", I guess this is the model name.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this manufacturer, but every significant appliance and home product will have a maker's plate (in metal, or sometimes heavy plastic) that will disclose the model number and serial number. A serial number is individual to the unit; a model number, on the other hand, will be the same on every identical unit no matter how many are produced. Model numbers are always letters and numbers; I've never seen a model number using words. "Design Inverter" may be the name under which this item is sold, but the item's _name_ is not the same as its _model number._"

Comment: I attached a picture of the unit. I do not see any metal or plastic plate attached on any side of it.

Comment: Is there a cover you removed to get access to the filter? If so, it's likely that the maker's plate is located on the inside of the cover or in the covered area.